# Multinomial Theorem changed summation constrains

Tags: summation, multinomial-coefficients, multinomial-theorem

I know that a factorized polynomial can be written in the following way:

$$(x_{11}+...+x_{1n})^{a_1}...(x_{n1}+...+x_{nn})^{a_n}=\sum_{k_{11}+...+k_{1n}=a_1\\\quad\quad\vdots\\k_{n1}+...+k_{nn}=a_n\\}\binom{a_1}{k_{11},...,k_{1n}}...\binom{a_n}{k_{n1},...,k_{nn}}x_{11}^{k_{11}}x_{12}^{k_{12}}...x_{nn}^{k_{nn}}$$

While solving another problem I stubled upon a slightly different sum:

\begin{align*}
&\sum_{k_{11}+...+k_{1n}=a_1\\\quad\quad\vdots\\k_{n1}+...+k_{nn}=a_n\\}\frac{(k_{11}+...+k_{n1})!}{k_{11}!...k_{1n}!}...\frac{(k_{1n}+...+k_{nn})!}{k_{n1}!...k_{nn}!}x_{11}^{k_{11}}x_{12}^{k_{12}}...x_{nn}^{k_{nn}} \\ =&\sum_{k_{11}+...+k_{1n}=a_1\\\quad\quad\vdots\\k_{n1}+...+k_{nn}=a_n\\}\binom{k_{11}+...+k_{n1}}{k_{11},...,k_{n1}}...\binom{k_{1n}+...+k_{nn}}{k_{1n},...,k_{nn}}x_{11}^{k_{11}}x_{12}^{k_{12}}...x_{nn}^{k_{nn}}
\end{align*}

The difference consists in the "vertical" summation instead of the "horizontal" of the $k_{ij}$ in the multinomial coefficient.
Are there still any possible ways to simplify this sum?

Comment: How do you define a multinomial with $a_j\ne\sum_i k_{ij}$?

Comment: @user You are right. That was abuse of notation. It's defined in the sense of factorial of the upper divided by the factorials of the lower.